# Method of Passing Two values in CheckBoxList selections

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an enrolment wizard on a student portal where students choose their modules each academic year. They have a choice of modules and each module carries a number of points and students are restricted to a certain number of points depending on their course. I have the asp.net code below that has a `CheckBoxList` `module_choice` of all available modules for that academic year.

```
<asp:View ID="semester_1_view" runat="server">

    <p>CATS points Required:</p>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cat_points_total" runat="server" DataSourceID="semester" 
        DataTextField="cats_points_total" DataValueField="cats_points_total" 
        Visible="true"></asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="module_choice" runat="server" DataSourceID="semester" 
        DataTextField="module_name" DataValueField="cats_points"></asp:CheckBoxList>
    <asp:Label ID="sem_1_fb" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="sem_1_cat" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="sem_1_cat_Click" />
    <asp:Button CommandName="NextView" ID="btnnext2" runat="server" Text="Next" 
        OnClick="btnnext2_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName="PrevView" Text="Previous" 
        CssClass="submitbtn" />
</asp:View>
```

At the moment this only passes the `cats_points` I also want some method to pass the `module_id` of the selected items.

I then have the following C# that calculates the total of cats points selected and provides feedback whether the total selected equals the total required or not.

```
protected void sem_1_cat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int catselected = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < module_choice.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (module_choice.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                string value = module_choice.Items[i].Value;
                catselected += int.Parse(value);
            }
        }
        int cattotal = int.Parse(cat_points_total.SelectedValue);
        int catcalc = cattotal - catselected;
        int zero = 0;

        if (catcalc != zero)
        {
            sem_1_fb.Visible = true;
            sem_1_fb.Text = "<b> Not Enough Points</b> cattotal =" + cattotal + " catselected =" + catselected + " catcalc =" + catcalc +".";
        }

        else
        {
            sem_1_fb.Visible = true;
            sem_1_fb.Text = "<b>Point Criteria Met</b> cattotal =" + cattotal + " catselected =" + catselected + " catcalc =" + catcalc +".";
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to run a check that the total is correct and if it is insert the selected `module_id` from each selection into a database with something similar to this but obviously at the moment I do not have the `module_id` information to do so only the `cats_points`;

```
int count = module_choice.Items.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (moduleselect.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                string value = module_choice.Items[i].Value;

                String query = "INSERT INTO students_vs_modules (user_id, module_id) 
                VALUES (@user_id, @module_id)";

                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", user);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@module_id", value);

                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am fairly new to C#

## EDIT

This is the datasource I use to populate the `module_choice` CheckBoxList

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="semester" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT modules.module_id, modules.module_name, modules.module_tutor, 
    staff_records.f_name, staff_records.l_name, modules.compulsory, modules.year, 
    modules.cats_points, modules.description, courses.course_name, 
    student_records.user_id, courses.cats_points_total 
    FROM modules 
    INNER JOIN courses_vs_modules ON modules.module_id = courses_vs_modules.module_id 
    INNER JOIN staff_records ON modules.module_tutor = staff_records.user_id 
    INNER JOIN courses ON courses_vs_modules.course_id = courses.course_id 
    INNER JOIN student_records ON courses.course_id = student_records.course_id 
    WHERE (student_records.user_id = @user_id)"
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [students_vs_modules]([user_id], [module_id]) 
    VALUES (@user_id, @module_id)">
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="user_id" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="module_id" Type="Int32" />
</InsertParameters>
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="user_id" Name="user_id" Type="Int32"></asp:QueryStringParameter>
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: How are you populating module_choice checkboxlist ?

Comment: @DinoMyte I have updated my question with the datasource I use to populate the `module_choice` checkboxlist.

Comment: Thanks. What is module_id in the context ?

Comment: @DinoMyte As in the value? There will be multiple selections so there will be multiple values, they are all 4 digit ints starting at 2000 and auto increment with each insert. Or do you mean what the module_id is used for? As it is the unique primary key in the `modules` table and is also used to link other tables through lookup tables, an example being `students_vs_modules` where it links a student to a module. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to store `module_id` & `cat_points` for each listed `module_name` in the CheckBoxList & on selection of check boxes you want to get hold of the selected `module_id` & `cat_points`.

Out of the box `CheckBoxList` has a `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` (to represent the text to show and the corresponding value). You could extend the `CheckBoxList` control to hold an additional value.

However the easiest option would be to return the concatenated value with a delimiter from the data source and use this as the `DataValueField`. Now when you are processing you can split the selected value and get hold of the separate values (under `sem_1_cat_Click` event)

In your case `cats_points` & `module_id` can be combined into a single field called `mod_id_catpoints` (which could be for example like `23**345` where `**` is the delimiter)

In this case `mod_id_catpoints` will be your `DataValueField`

Under `sem_1_cat_Click event` you would split `23**345` into `23` and `345` where `23` would be the `module_id` and `245` would be the `cat_points`